# Traverse a file tree without recursion and with stack Java

Tags: java, path

Please, how to traverse a file tree/directory without recursion and with stack using Java.

```
public void traverse(Path path)
throws IOException
{
    Stack<Stream<Path>> st = new Stack<>();
    st.add(Files.list(path));
    for(Iterator<Path> it = st.peek().iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
    {
        Path temp = it.next();
        final BasicFileAttributes fa = Files.readAttributes(temp, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        if(fa.isDirectory())
        {
            //list all the directory contents
            st.push(Files.list(temp));
        }
        else if(fa.isRegularFile())
        {
        }
        else if(fa.isSymbolicLink()) {} //symbolic link
        else if(fa.isOther()) {} //other
        else {}
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you have a tree of paths. Traverse it as you would any other tree. 
They offer a nice example for iterative, stack assisted, in-order, traversal of a binary tree [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-solution-of-binary-tree-inorder-traversal-in-java/).

Try expanding that.

All the stack does is offer you some "memory" of where you came from so you can go back up the tree when failing to find what you need in the current branch.